# Cloud9 Sync with Local Repo

Tags: git, cloud9-ide

I'm new to git. I just setup my git server with SSH.

I'm using Cloud9 as my IDE because it's easy to use on the go...

I've created a git repo for my project. I'm not sure if it's important to note but I added existing files to create this repo. It has a bunch of files, folders, and a .git directory.

I have cloned this repo to Cloud9. The repo is created as a sub-directory. I'm not sure how to move this but it's where it's at for now.

I have a headless server so I'll be making all of my changes in Cloud9. I'd prefer to use push or equivalent to sync changes as I'll be working with the files in a browser and it's a lot easier for me to do it in front of me than open a new SSH session, connect to my server and then run a pull.

I've tried pushing to my repo from Cloud9 but it's not updating. It shows "Everything up-to-date but when I look at the files on my server they are not updated. Here's what I ran to get where I'm at now:

```
git init                              //Worked fine
git commit -a -m "Message"            //Worked fine
git clone [remote server]:[repo]      //Worked fine
git push --all [remote server]:[repo]  //Not working
```

**How can I keep my local repo in-sync with Cloud9?**

Comment: Can you clarify the git commands you used? Those do not look like valid git commands.  For instance, what do you mean by `[remote server]`?  When doing a push you just specify the remote name as from `git remote` and the branch name `[local[:remote]]`.

Comment: git clone me@myserver:myrepo worked for me. I need to run git remote before git push?

Comment: A sorry, yes in `git clone` that's correct.  I was referencing the `[remote server]` in the `git push` command.  You don't need to run `git remote`, but the remote names you use for `git push` are the same names you see if you do run `git remote`.